# How to take cross origin screenshots using html2canvas-proxy

Tags: proxy, html2canvas

Struggling to use the [html2canvas-proxy](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas-proxy-nodejs) for cross origin screenshots. As far as I understand, passing the url as a parameter(`localhost:xxxx?url=https://...`) returns the image screenshot data as a base 64 string ([check blob](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas-proxy-nodejs/blob/5d4cf02de2cb983747b5ea56a4e320ef21d329c5/server.js#L29)).
This works only if the `url` parameter is an image source. On using any other url and using the same as an image source, I just get the alt text.

For example the proxy works with https://placebear.com/200/300 but fails to work with https://google.com as the url parameter.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **html2canvas-proxy** is only intended for use in combination with the **html2canvas** library itself. It's a NodeJS server with CORS enabled so that html2canvas can send the cross-domain image URLs to and receive the corresponding base64 data URL for processing in the canvases.

It doesn't work as a server that takes in a website URL and returns a screenshot of that website.